# Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value when try modify expression

Tags: c#, .net

I have a expression and want to modify it. Just add code before and after the expression:

```
private Expression<Action<T>> GenerateMethodCallWithMoniroting<T>(string recurringJobId, Expression<Action<T>> methodCall)
{
   return m =>
   {
     var transaction = Agent.Tracer.StartTransaction(recurringJobId, ApiConstants.ActionExec);
     try
     {
       return methodCall.Compile().Invoke(m); //error here 
     }
     finally
     {
       transaction?.End();
     }
  };
}
```

I commented where it shows the error `Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value`

I don't quite understand how to fix it...

Comment: Try to delete the return word and just call the method

Comment: @Raziak already try this way, it still return an error

Comment: Mmmm... Maybe try to change the return type of the anonymous function to something like this: private Expression<Func<T, TResult>> GenerateMethodCallWithMoniroting<T, TResult> with the return

Comment: have you tried to remove return from "return methodCall.Compile().Invoke(m);"

Comment: Currently you have an expression that you compile into an action and then you invoke the action. The return type of the action is void, because actions do not return anything: hence the compiler warning. So removing that return removes that warning. Then you would get another warning because you would try to return an action as an expression, which won't work because "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree". Are you sure you need expressions instead of lambdas?

Comment: + You probably should rename your method to GenerateMethodCallWithMonitoring :)